# Elementor Wodpress - Header widget paragraph spacing issues

Tags: wordpress, elementor

paragraph spacing is not working in the Heading widget.
When I select the text, it displays fine, but when I step out of that area, they lose the spaces.
Please see the images to see just the problem.
WP version: 5.8.2
Elementor free version: 3.4.7
Fresh installation: ZERO additional plugins
Theme: Hello of Elementor

When I select the text, it displays fine (image):
https://elchatel.com/elementor/img00.png

But when I step out of that area, they lose the spaces (image)
https://elchatel.com/elementor/img01.png

The setup is (image):
https://elchatel.com/elementor/img02.png

**CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASE?**

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br />` tags where you want the spaces

Comment: The answer is definitely bad. He is not a tech savvy. I thought that a specialist could answer, but it seems that not even the administrator knows it, and that is why he marks the question negative. YOU SHOULD CHANGE THE ADMINISTRATOR WHO IS ONLY CRITICISM BUT DOES NOT CONTRIBUTE ANYTHING.